# How to decrypt id_rsa private key?

Tags: ssh

total linux beginner here.

So I just installed https://github.com/niruix/sshwifty on my server. I only use SSH keys to log into my server. My SSH keys are protected by a passphrase.

Now when I want to connect to my server through sshwifty it asks me to provide my private key. [image: Img]

[image]

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,20DD60A29753E6F89413A2F03DE8B20F
```

My private key is still encrypted and I assume I have to decyrpt it and paste that output into Sshwifty.

What I already tried:

[image]

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in id_rsa -out dec_rsa
```

This gives me a bad magic number error.

Appreciate the help

Comment: I've never used this program. What makes you think that the key has to be decrypted? (it would probably decrypt to binary data)

Comment: I tried pasting the unencrypted private key and it didnt work. Thats why I assume that I have to decrypt it first.

Comment: "Didn't work"? So, what happened? I could try it myself, but I'm a bit uneasy about pasting my secret SSH key into a program I don't know anything about, even if it was a temporary key.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RvPCVNS.png

> Connection failed
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no key found

Comment: I wonder if they use the word "encrypted" to mean "encrypted with a passphrase" and if the program requires a key with _no_ passphrase?

Comment: Im not sure. I dont understand why I cant decrypt my private key though.

Comment: What I meant was: Try with a key that has no passphrase.

Comment: i'm sure there are uses for this sshwifty program but i can't help wondering why anyone would want to put their private keys on a web app without even a pass-phrase to protect them, even if they ran it on their own hardware.   that's a massive increase to the attack surface.

Comment: OTOH I'm paranoid and won't even use my own android tablet to ssh to my linux boxes.   the tablet's on the same WLAN, running Lineage, with only a handful of open-source apps from fdroid installed....I still regard it as an untrustworthy device.

Comment: Are you downloading the web-tool using (TSL) https? If not then you should not trust it. If so, then you have TSL so no need for ssh.

Answer (score 17):

The command is `openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

If the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is encrypted, `openssl` will ask you for the passphrase to decrypt the private key, otherwise, the key will be directly outputted on the screen.

But with that been said, you **SHOULDN'T** use `id_rsa` file. Because Sshwifty is doing SSH stuff on the backend. Meaning **the private key you give to it will be sent to the backend server through the network**, which is kind horrible since private key is intend to only lives on your local machine and should *never* be send to anybody else.

However, we're dealing with design compromise here: Sshwifty backend needs the private key to be able to authenticate with the SSH server for you. So, to better protect yourself, you can generate a SSH key pair to use specifically in Sshwifty.

To generate the private key, run command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my_server`, and when been asked for `Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):`, just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> so `openssl` will not encrypt the private key.

After the command is succeed, you will found two new files under `~/.ssh/` directory: `my_server` which is the private key that you can use in Sshwifty when connecting to the SSH server, and `my_server.pub` which is the public key that you need to deploy on your SSH server.

In this case, if the `my_server` is for some reason leaked, only one server will be effected.

---

Now, let's talk about the "design compromise".

When designing the software, I spend sometime to find a SSH client library that could work inside a web browser, but I failed to found a reliable one if any. After that, I spend a bit more time reading SSH specs, and eventually decided that it is impossible for me to implement such complex protocol safely within given deadline.

So, I settled on the current design, not only because it's a time saver, but also because it's been battle tested, and should provide expected safety.

And yes, I'm the author of Sshwifty who happened to Google the name of my software due to boredom, and landed on this page. For the record: I totally did not posting questions to advertise my software.

---

Hope this answer helps. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your english is fine. After running this command i get this error: 

139869952369088:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:537:
139869952369088:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:461:

Comment: `openssl rsa` command giving you error? Maybe try `ssh-keygen -p`, this will set a new passphrase to the `id_rsa` file (Or decrypt it if you give it an empty new passphrase). The `ssh-keygen -p` command will overwrite the `id_rsa` file, you may want to back it up first.

Answer (score 5):

If your desire is to "decrypt" an SSH key so it does not require a password anymore, you can do so by running this command:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/<private key file>
```

This is the command to change the password for a private key. You will need to enter the password and then the new password. If you just press enter for the new password it will be stored without a password.

Comment: If you get `Bad passphrase.`, then you might need to convert the key from an "OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY" to "RSA PRIVATE KEY" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817907/446106)